# Complex queries with dynamoose

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, dynamoose

I am trying to perform a complex filter operation with dynamoose query and I unable to get the syntax correct.

For eg: Trying to filter height and weight of dogs and breed type

```
Dog.query({ breed: 'poodle', height : { gt : 10 , le : 15 } , weight : { gt : 2 , le : 5} },
    {
      conditionalOperator: 'AND'
    }).exec().then(dogs => console.log(dogs))
```

Also, Could any one provide the Model schema definition to achieve the above filters.